# When was transferred file actually created?

Tags: windows, attributes

When a file is downloaded, in a Date Of Creation in it's attributes indicated the time when it was downloaded, not when it was originally created. Is there a way to find the actual date, be it text, sound or video file?

Answer (score 2):

Only if the filesystem** metadata was also downloaded. Unless the file was in some kind of container (like a zip file) the created time is not saved.

(**Some formats, like photos, will have [their own metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) seperate from the filesystem that can include a timestamp of when the photo was taken. That file metadata would be saved)

Comment: Great. But how do I know it besides looking at the properties(which turn useless)?

Comment: If the file format does not store the info itself(check the `details` tab under properties), there is no way. When you download from the internet it does not preserve the create/modified/accessed times.